# Given Twilio states 1 sms per second - do I need to modify my bulk sending sms function? - Django

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

On their pricing page Twilio states one sms per second for "clean local numbers". Does this mean I cannot send more than one sms per second for that number https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/us

I'm using the following code and it seems to be working in terms of sending sms to subscriber phone numbers:

```
for subscriber in subscribers:
    subscriber_num = subscriber.phone_number
    my_sms = "My message to subscribers"
    client.messages.create(
        to= subscriber_num,
        from_=reviewnum,
        body=my_sms
    )
```

Should I modify my code to take into account *one sms per second for "clean local numbers"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio will queue SMS segments if you exceed 1 segment per second, up to [4 hours](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues) worth of segments can be queued and will drain at 1 segment per second.

You can set the maximum lifetime a segment will remain in queue with the [validity period](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/take-more-control-of-outbound-messages-using-validity-period.html) (default is 4 hours), keeping in mind you don't want SMS segments to be delivered past normal business hours.

Comment: Got it. If I had a 100 twilio phone numbers, and sent out 100 sms, one sms from each Twilio number, would they all go out immediately, without queueing?

Comment: Yes. As long as that Message is 160 characters or less using GSM-7 encoding or 70 characters using UCS-2 encoding.